# When exporting multiple kubeconfigs in kubectl, only one works at a time

Tags: kubernetes

There are two working Kubernetes clusters and trying to use context to manage those.

**Kubernetes:1.27**

**OS: Ubuntu 20.04**

Both have working kubeconfig files named lab5 and lab6
if i try these kubeconfigs individually then it works

```
kubectl config view --kubeconfig=/home/user1/lab5
```

```
kubectl config view --kubeconfig=/home/user1/lab6
```

but after exporting both files it works only for the first entry before the "**:**"

```
root@lab5:/home/user1# export KUBECONFIG=/home/user1/lab5:/home/user1/lab6


kubectl config get-contexts


kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                       CLUSTER   AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
          kubernetes-admin@lab5   lab5   kubernetes-admin
*         kubernetes-admin@lab6   lab6   kubernetes-admin



root@lab5:/home/user1# kubectl get po  --context kubernetes-admin@lab6
**error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)**

root@lab5:/home/user1# kubectl get po  --context kubernetes-admin@lab5
No resources found in default namespace.

root@lab5:/home/user1# export KUBECONFIG=/home/user1/lab6:/home/user1/lab5

root@lab5:/home/user1# kubectl get po  --context kubernetes-admin@lab6
No resources found in default namespace.

root@lab5:/home/user1#  kubectl get po  --context kubernetes-admin@lab5
**error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)**
```

any idea about this behaviour

should be able to run commands against both clusters using contexts

Answer (score 0):

the username was same on both clusters. Updating to different user-names solved the issue